# Changing Textinput Size using kivy

Tags: android, python, layout, kivy, textinput

I'm having some trouble using kivy.  My goal is to create labels next to the textinput boxes so people remember what they are supposed to be typing in.  I would like to be able to resize the textinput boxes or if there is a better way please let me know!

```
<Phone>:
result: _result
h: _h
w: _w


AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'top'

    ScreenManager:
        size_hint: 1, .9
        id: _screen_manager
        Screen:
            name: 'home'
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    source: "/home/aaron/Desktop/main.png"
            Label:
                markup: True
                text: '[size=50][color=ff3333]Welcome to [color=ff3333]Diabetes Manager[/color][/size]'
        Screen:
            name: 'menu'
            GridLayout: 
                cols: 2
                padding: 50
                canvas.before:
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                        source: "/home/aaron/Desktop/main.png"

                Button:
                    text: 'My Profile'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'profile' 
                Button:
                    text: 'History'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'history'     

                Button:
                    text: 'New Entry'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'new_entry' 
                Button:
                    text: 'Graph'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'graph' 
                Button:
                    text: 'Diet'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'diet' 
                Button:
                    text: 'Settings'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'settings' 

        Screen:
            name: 'profile'
            GridLayout: 
                rows: 1
                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        text: 'Name'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _name
                        hint_text: 'Name'

                    Label:  
                        text: 'Gender'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _gender1
                        hint_text: 'Gender'

                    Label:
                        text: 'Type of Diabetes'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _type
                        hint_text: 'Type of Diabetes'

                    Label:
                        text: 'Height(in)'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _h
                        hint_text: 'Height in inches'

                    Label:
                        text: 'Weight(lb)'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _w
                        hint_text: 'Weight in pounds'

                    Label:
                        id:_result
                        text: 'BMI'
                    Button:
                        text: 'Calculate BMI'
                        on_press: root.product(*args)

                    Label:
                        text: 'List of Medications'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _meds
                        hint_text: 'List of Medications'

                    Label:
                        text: 'Insulin Times'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _times
                        hint_text: 'Please Enter Times to Take Insulin'


        Screen:
            name: 'history'
            GridLayout: 
                cols:1

        Screen:
            name: 'new_entry'
            GridLayout:
                cols:1
                TextInput:
                    id: _time
                    text: 'Please Enter The Current Time'
                TextInput:
                    id: _glucose_reading
                    text: 'Please Enter Your Current Blood Sugar'
                TextInput:
                    id: _food
                    text: 'Please Enter Amount of Carbs for The Meal'
                TextInput:
                    id: _meds_taken
                    text: 'Please Enter Any Medications Taken'


        Screen:
            name: 'graph'
            GridLayout: 
                cols: 3
                padding: 50
            Label: 
                markup: True
                text: '[size=24][color=dd88ff]Your Graph[/color][/size]'

        Screen:
            name: 'diet'
            GridLayout: 
                cols: 3
                padding: 50
            Label: 
                markup: True
                text: '[size=24][color=dd88ff]Reccomended Diet[/color][/size]'


        Screen:
            name: 'settings'
            GridLayout: 
                cols: 3
                padding: 50
            Label: 
                markup: True
                text: '[size=24][color=dd88ff]Settings[/color][/size]'


AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'bottom'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint: 1, .1
        Button:
            id: btnExit
            text: 'Exit'
            on_press: app.stop() 
        Button:
            text: 'Menu'
            on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'menu'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use another layout inside your `GridLayout` for each `TextInput`, which will create a widget with two widgets inside: Label and TextInput. The result will look like this:

```
Screen:
    name: 'profile'
    GridLayout: 
        cols: 1
        BoxLayout: ## Box 1
            Label:
                text: 'Name Please'                    
            TextInput:
                id: _name
        BoxLayout: ## Box 2
            Label:
                text: 'Another Name Please'                    
            TextInput:
                id: _name
```

With `size_hint` you can set sizes of Label or TextInput inside BoxLayout and even BoxLayout itself.

Or there is another way - [hint_text](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.hint_text) which will display inside your TextInput when it's empty.

**Example:**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
Builder.load_string('''
<Test>:
    GridLayout: 
        cols: 1
        BoxLayout: ## here is one Box
            Label:
                text: 'Name Please'                    
            TextInput:
        BoxLayout: ## here is another Box
            Label:
                text: 'Name Please'                    
            TextInput:
''')
class Test(ScrollView):pass
runTouchApp(Test())
```

Comment: @Azaro actually, it looks like [this](https://kivy.org/docs/_images/guide_customize_step1.png), where whole layout is Grid and each two Label+TextInput are in a Box which goes down the whole length. Sorry if I understood it wrong, please show some image how it should look like.

Comment: This does not really work. It makes everything vertical and the boxes still go down the whole length of the screen.  Hint_text works ok but if someone enters something then they have to delete the input in order to see what the text box is for.

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean by "it makes everything vertical". Default BoxLayout's orientation is `horizontal` therefore its widgets will be perpendicular to GridLayout's line direction of adding widgets. If you want it to be "horizontal", then instead of `cols: 1` use `rows: 1` and add to each BoxLayout `orientation: 'vertical'` Or do you mean by vertical that Label's text is centered? Please, provide some image how it should look like.

Comment: Your picture is exactly what I want it to do.  This is what it looks like when I added boxlayout [link](http://postimg.org/image/71tbqr6n1/)

Comment: @Azaro: then you have some BoxLayout without `orientation='vertical'` in your code above the `Screen:` part of your kv code, because this code works. I added a copy&run example. There's another option - you used "Screen" as a name for your class and it looks in your code like this: `class Screen(BoxLayout):` which is by default _horizontal_ so you'd need to edit the orientation in the class/kv rule. If that's the case, using names of kivy widgets as your class is not recommended and can cripple your app.

Comment: I added my full .kv file if you can take a look and see if anything can make it work.

Comment: @Azaro You used BoxLayout for _all_ widgets, not only Label+TextInput combo. Ah, I'll edit it a little more.

Comment: Perfect thank you for all of your help.  Now is there a way to stretch the input boxes a little more to the left?

Comment: @Azaro of course, that's the line under my first code. Just add `size_hint_x: number` to either Label or TextInput and set it to: if Label - less than 0.5, if TextInput, greater than 0.5.